# Inserção e remoção usando PDO em relacionamentos OneToMany e ManyToMany

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Eu dúvidas de principiante sobre inserção e remoção usando **PDO** em relacionamentos do tipo **OneToMany** e **ManyToMany**. Exemplo:

```
class Livro{
   private $id;
   private $titulo;
   private $generos; //Livro tem mais de um genero
}

class Genero{
   private $id;
   private $nome;
}
```

O relacionamento é OneToMany, ou seja, um livro tem muitos gêneros. Se no BD eu tiver uma JoinTable (`livro_genero`) como faço o `insert` usando **PDO**? E se a relação for ManyToMany?

```
class Funcionario{
   private $id;
   private $nome;
   private $projetos; //Um funcionario pode participar de vários projetos
}

class Projeto{
   private $id;
   private $titulo;
   private $funcionarios; //Um projeto tem vários funcionarios
}
```

No banco eu tenho as tabelas `funcionario`, `projeto` e `funcionario_has_projeto`.

PS: Eu não posso usar o Doctrine, por isso eu gostaria de exemplos de como fazer isso sem usar um ORM e usando o MySQL.

Comment: você quer simular o comportamento ORM então?

Comment: Mais ou menos isso.